# How do I select the min and max values using a self join

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like this:

```
pk client value date
1  001     564  2012/5/1
2  002     245  2012/6/1
3  003     445  2012/6/6
4  001     845  2012/7/1
5  002     567  2012/8/1
6  001     123  2012/9/1
```

I know this can be solved with the greatest n per group and a self join, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Basically this is what I want for my output

```
client min(value) max(value) date_for_min(value) date_for_max(value)
001    123        845        2012/9/1            2012/7/1
002    245        567        2012/6/1            2012/8/1
003    445        445        2012/6/6            2012/6/6
```

The tricky part is getting only one row for each client with the min /  max values and then the other columns that go along with those min / max values. Any ideas?

Comment: do you wan the `date_for_min(value)` and `date_for_max(value)` to be the values associated with the `min(value)` and then the `max(value)`?  If so, then it looks like the dates on client `001` are incorrect.  Can you please confirm?

Comment: Good catch. Yes, I wanted the dates associated with the min / max values. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case there are multiple rows for some min or max value (for same client), I have given you the earliest date that they appear:

```
select t1.client, t1.MinValue, t1.MaxValue, min(t2.date) as date_for_min_value, min(t3.date) as date_for_max_value
from (
    select client, min(value) as MinValue, max(value) as MaxValue
    from MyTable
    group by client
) t1
inner join MyTable t2 on t1.client = t2.client and t1.MinValue = t2.Value
inner join MyTable t3 on t1.client = t3.client and t1.MaxValue = t3.Value
group by t1.client, t1.MinValue, t1.MaxValue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
select distinct t1.client, t1.mnval, mindate.dt, t1.mxval, maxdate.dt
from
(
    select min(value) mnval, max(value) mxVal, client
    from yourtable
    group by client
) t1
inner join yourtable t2
    on t1.client = t2.client
inner join yourtable mindate
    on t1.client = mindate.client
    and t1.mnval = mindate.value
inner join yourtable maxdate
    on t1.client = maxdate.client
    and t1.mxVal = maxdate.value
```